# Blazor-Server ProtectedSessionStorage SetAsync returns task cancled exception when called after a rest call

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am writing a microservice with a micro frontend that is embedded in a balzor server application. This microservice provides a login function. The front end calls the mentioned login function via a POST request and gets as a return value a generated access token. I want to save this token in the browser's session storage via the ProtectedSessionStorage to have it secure.
Now the problem: If I call the SetAsync method with static parameters it works flawlessly. If I call my microservice's login function via REST-POST to obtain my token, it never returns and eventually fails in a Task canceled exception.

I tried to save something to the storage like this:

```
private async void Login()
{
    string token = "testToken"
    await ProtectedSessionStorage.SetAsync("access", token);
}
```

this worked.

Then I tried to obtain my token via REST-like this:

```
public class TokenContainer
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}

private async void Login()
{
    TokenContanier tokens = await LoginService.LoginSync(VM.Username, VM.Password);
    await ProtectedSessionStorage.SetAsync("access", tokens.AccessToken);
}

internal async Task<AuthenticatedUserResponse?> LoginSync(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        var request = new LoginRequest() { Password = password, Username = username };
        var stringContent = GetContentFromContainer(request);
        var response = await this.Client.PostAsync($"{BASE_ROUTE}/{LOGIN_ACTION}", stringContent);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var authResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuthenticatedUserResponse>(content, JsonOptions);
                return authResponse;
            }

            return null;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This did not work. The LoginService was injected via Dependency Injection.

Comment: Most likelike issue is with token retrieval from your service endpoint, not with the protected storage. Check the network tab via browser for http status code.

Comment: @MaxNaumov No, the token is received successfully. The POST is completed and the data is parsed, I checked with the debugger.

Comment: There is potentially a world of difference between `token` [a string] and `tokens.Access` [???].  Without that knowledge, it's impossible to answer your question with any authority.  The most obvious guess is `tokens.Access` isn't serializable.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Sorry for not beeing clear enough, thats just a string property in a contanier. I added the contanier for clarification.

Comment: You need to put a break point in here - `    await ProtectedSessionStorage.SetAsync("access", tokens.AccessToken);
 and check the content of `tokens.AccessToken`.  If necessary copy the string into the first block and test it.  `

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I solved it, please see my answer below. Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: 'form' does a post on submit.  You should either be using 'EditForm' or no form.  It's expected classic standard Html form behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For anybody who is stumbling upon the same or similar issue, I just found the problem.

The problem was that my login "form" was inside a literal html <form> tag, which is, as I suppose, logically the right choice. 
 I dont know why, but as soon as I submit the form (pressing my login button and calling my LoginSync() function **the scope of the site gets (probably disposed of before) reopened**.
I found that behavior because I set a breakpoint in the OnInitialized() method and observed that it hit that breakpoint **every time I pressed the button**... It seemes as if the browser lost the connection between the session and the scope.

As soon as I removed the <form> enclosure around my input fields, it worked as expected. The rest call fetched my token successfull and the ProtectedSessionStorage stored it successfully aswell.

If anybody knows why this happens or if this is intended behavior please let me know :)

Before (**Did not work**):

```
<form>
    <input @bind="Username" type="text" placeholder="username" />
    <input @bind="Password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
    <button @onclick="@LoginSync">login</button>
</form>
```

After (**Did work**):

```
<input @bind="Username" type="text" placeholder="username" />
<input @bind="Password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
<button @onclick="@LoginSync">login</button>
```